# How can I create a make file using Plugin builder with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, plugins, windows-7

I am using the plugin "plugin builder" to generate a template. The plugin builder is also generating a `make` file. I am working on a computer using windows 7 and am trying to execute the `make` file using the command line of Windows (MS Dos). However, this doesen't work. This means that my `*.ui` and my `*.qrc` file are not compiled to python, if I understand correctly.

What can I do? I am not very familiar with pc or programming so I hope to finde someone who can give me an easy understandable answer. Thank you.

Comment: Consider posting this question on SE Stack Overflow--you may get more precise answers.

Comment: If this question is about QGIS you may want to mention it somewhere in the title and in the question.

Comment: never tried that "plugin builder" but if "make" is a command to run inside python, consider that the windows console is not going to understand that command. Maybe you have to type in windows console "python" in order to activate python prompt, and then, type "make" because you will be already in python context. Good luck and yes, consider asking in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Run the code in the osgeo4w Shell

And follow the steps in here:

http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/plugins_tutorial.html

If the osgeo4w shell doesn't work copy the qtcore4.dll and qtgui4.dll to the windows system directory first

Regards

Comment: thank you for your answer. I downloaded the osgeo4w shell and tried to run the "make" file. However, it doesnt work. Also your hint to copy the two *.dll files into the windows system directory.
Maybe i put them in the wrong place. Do I need to put them in a specific sub directory?
Thanks again
Z.

Comment: You should put it in C:\Windows\system. Create the folder if you dont have it. It works here in Windows 7 64bits.

Answer (score 0):

'make', works in linux by default as it is part of its build system. For windows, you could try downloading GNU Make Setup from below link

[GNU make link](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm)

afterwards, you should be able to run 'make' from your dos prompt